# How to find number of characters per word in a list? (Java)

Tags: java, string, list

I want the output to say

Total letters per word is:

Emma = 4

Taylor = 6

Jacob = 5

Roger = 5

JP = 2

I am aware that my for loop is wrong it outputs total chars of all names.

> Blockquote

```
public static void main(String[] args){

List<String> myList = Arrays.asList("Emma", "Taylor", "Jacob", "Roger", "JP");// list of names

String[] arrayOfNames = new String[myList.size()]; 

myList.toArray(arrayOfNames);


    System.out.println("List of names: " +
    Arrays.toString(arrayOfNames));

    String myL = myList.toString();

    String[] words = myL.split(" ");

    int total = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) //for loop incorrect

      {

        total += words[i].length();
      }

         System.out.println("Total letters per word is: "+total);//see above

       }
}
```

> Blockquote

Comment: You over complicated things here. You just need 5 lines of code.

Comment: You _could_ use streams and go for something like `myList.stream().mapToInt(String::length).sum()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are making it over complicated than it needs to be try something like this:

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    List<String> myList = Arrays.asList("Emma", "Taylor", "Jacob", "Roger", "JP");
    System.out.println("Total letters per word is: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < myList.size(); i++) //for loop incorrect
    {
    System.out.println(myList.get(i)+" = " + myList.get(i).length());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! just what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

For example you can do it like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    List<String> words = Arrays.asList("Emma", "Taylor", "Jacob", "Roger", "JP");// list of names

    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("Total letters per word is: \n");
    for (String word: words) {
        builder.append(word + ": " + word.length() + "\n");
    }

    System.out.println(builder.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just iterate over `myList` and print out the length of each word (the amount of characters) like this:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> myList = Arrays.asList("Emma", "Taylor", "Jacob", "Roger", "JP");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(myList.toArray()));
    System.out.println("Total letters per word is: ");
    for(String name : myList) {
      System.out.printf("%s = %d\n", name, name.length());
    }
  }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[Emma, Taylor, Jacob, Roger, JP]
Total letters per word is:
Emma = 4
Taylor = 6
Jacob = 5
Roger = 5
JP = 2
```

Test it [here!](https://repl.it/Fuhh/2)

Comment: Thanks you're awesome! I haven't programmed in so long I'm taking up a new class in programming and got stuck thanks!.